# Changing the input value in real time with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I am having a problem changing the input value text to reflect the same on the site in real time. I am able to change the buttons text value in the html but it does not reflect the change on the site. I assume this is b/c it changes the value after the page loads. Is there a way to make this happen? I need to change its value to Spanish and this cart page is a hosted solution so it must be done by javascript/jQuery.

Any help would be awesome!

Live example: https://www.mcssl.com/SecureCart/Checkout.aspx?mid=A3C36989-8F1B-4C02-B59C-B62589F52BDB&sctoken=d31d3c20452f48b684ebbf476aec968b&bhcp=1

Here is the code.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('.actions input.return-cart').val('Retornar al Carrito');
});
```

Here is the html that shows it changed.

```
<div class="actions">
<input type="submit" class="button return-cart" id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_scPageContent_backToCartButton" value="Retornar al Carrito" name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$scPageContent$backToCartButton">
</div>
```

However the button shows "Return to Cart" instead of "Retornar al Carrito"

Comment: Can you show a live example? If it possible the text is in an image in the button?

Comment: we cannot see any .actions container here.

Comment: Sorry, it is contained within an `actions` div container. You can see a live example here: https://www.mcssl.com/SecureCart/Checkout.aspx?mid=A3C36989-8F1B-4C02-B59C-B62589F52BDB&sctoken=d31d3c20452f48b684ebbf476aec968b&bhcp=1

Comment: You don't have jQuery included on that site.

Comment: It appears to be there in the head. `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear the have jQuery. You'll need to either include that or rewrite your code in plain js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    document.querySelector('.actions input.return-cart').value = 'Retornar al Carrito';

});
```

Note querySelector has some legacy issues, so if you can include jQuery maybe do that or give the button an ID and use

```
document.getElementById()
```

Comment: It looks like he has some library on `$`, at least after load, but this will work fine.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work. Also, jquery is added in the head. Can you take a look?

Comment: You're including an HTTP version on an HTTPS page. Start the url with "//..." and no protocol

Comment: Good catch! I just fixed that. For some reason this text will not change on the site but does in the html. Any ideas?

Comment: The button will always show return to cart. It's using a background image that says "return to cart"

Comment: Man I feel so stupid!! LOL Thanks for pointing that out! Been a long day LOL

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the container element of the `input` has a class called `actions`.

Works as expected in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EJCvB/

**UPDATE**:

After looking at the live page you added to your question, I suspect the problem has to do with the console errors that are being thrown. Specifically:

1. [blocked] The page at https://www.mcssl.com/SecureCart/Checkout.aspx?mid=A3C36989-8F1B-4C02-B59C-B62589F52BDB&sctoken=d31d3c20452f48b684ebbf476aec968b&bhcp=1 ran insecure content from http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js.
   /SecureCart/Checkout.aspx?mid=A3C36989-8F1B-4C02-B59C-B62589F52BDB&sctoken=d31d3c20452f48b684ebbf476aec968b&bhcp=1:1
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Try loading jQuery using HTTPS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, the `actions` is the container which I just updated above.

Comment: For some reason not working on my end..

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess the class .actions isn't part of the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

$(".return-cart").attr('value', 'Retornar al Carrito'); //versions older than 1.6

$(".return-cart").prop('value', 'Retornar al Carrito'); //versions newer than 1.6

Comment: Thanks! I just tried this but it did not work. Still shows the English text :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EJCvB/1/  check this !

Comment: Thanks! For some odd reason it changes the html on my end but doesn't show the text on the site. I don't understand why...

Comment: Try this    //before jQuery 1.6
$('#input1').attr('defaultValue', 'this is the new value');
//after jQuery 1.5.2
$('#input1').attr('value', 'this is the new value');

Comment: Because its using the defaultValue , you need to change the defaultValue..try this  $('#input1').attr('defaultValue', 'this is the new value');

Answer (score 0):

$('#input1').val('this is the new value');

//before jQuery 1.6

$('#input1').attr('defaultValue', 'this is the new value');

//after jQuery 1.5.2

$('#input1').attr('value', 'this is the new value');

Try the above